# 3D rendering in Java - Where should I start?

Tags: java, 3d, rendering

I'm thinking of making a 3D renderer, I know all about the XYZ dimensions, and am an intermediate Java programmer. But what should I do for a basic renderer? It has to be really basic, what should I render? A cube, a pyramid? A sphere?

Any answer would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite first question for 3D rendering was that how to give feeling of depth with just two, perpendicular and angled from perspective, lines. Solve this and I am sure you will end up building your own 3D renderer.

Comment: So you mean lines that rotates and changes the degree of angle they form?

Comment: They don't have to have a motion, the motion will be what physics engine will accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I realized this is an old question but for anyone wondering I suggest you check out this page which goes through the concepts:

[stuff](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/series/lets-build-a-3d-graphics-software-engine--gamedev-12718)

Then check out this tutorial on creating a 3D rotating cube. It's really easy to convert python code to a language of choice.

[stuff](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-3d-graphics-tutorial/nodes-and-edges)

Theres also a javascript version here:

[stuff](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/3d-tutorial-3/1645062289)

Then check this out, it explains creating a 3D engine:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/06/13/tutorial-series-learning-how-to-write-a-3d-soft-engine-from-scratch-in-c-typescript-or-javascript.aspx